# Send html table data has same name

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

My table is showing two columns, "#" and "String". I have made the table with each td having its value shown through a text_field so the user can change the value and submit the changes.

The problem is how to send all the values with the form since each td has the same id and name making only the last td sent.

How do I send all the td values?

The table:

```
<%= form_for(@skein) do |s| %>
<table width="100%" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th width="20%" data-placeholder="Search">#</th>
  <th width="80%" data-placeholder="Search">String</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% @split_order_content.zip(@split_content).each do |number, string| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= s.text_field :string_id_bk, :value => number %></td>
      <td><%= s.text_field :string_id, :value => string %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>     
</tbody>
</table>

<%= s.submit "Save String File", id: "commit", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
```

HTML td rendered:

```
<td><input value="Ende&quot;" type="text" name="skein[string_id]" id="skein_string_id"></td>
```

Notice how the name and id will be the same, causing the data to overwrite the data sending just the last data.

The table has thousands of records. I cannot send each td as an attribute parameter, a parameter should be a long array.

Comment: <% @split_order_content.zip(@split_content).each do |number, string| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= s.text_field :string_id_bk, :value => number ,:id => s.id %></td>
      <td><%= s.text_field :string_id, :value => string ,:id => s.id%></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<% @split_order_content.zip(@split_content).each do |number, string| %>
<tr>
<td> <%= text_field_tag 'string_id_bk[]', number %> </td>
<td> <%= text_field_tag 'string_id []', string %> </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yeah this method places each td into an array. Thanks, plus 1

Comment: please remove the space in 'string_id []'

Comment: I don't think its going to let the edit work, since its one character. lol

Answer (score 0):

Give unique id for the text fields as shown below

```
<% @split_order_content.zip(@split_content).each do |number, string| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= s.text_field :string_id_bk, :value => number ,:input_html => { :id => '#{s.id}'+'bk' } %></td>
  <td><%= s.text_field :string_id, :value => string ,:input_html => { :id => s.id }%></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Hope that will help you

Comment: Undefined method 'id' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder...> This is really only half the answer. The form will submit an attribute for each value, I don't want that. I want the values in one attribute.

Comment: change that :input_html to html and chek
:html => { :id =>s.id}

Comment: This works,  id: 'blah' . But I cant' have the the form send over an attribute value for each td. It needs to be together with its column. So :string_id has all the values sent. Not thousands.

Comment: why do you want to put this logic in the view ??

Comment: To edit it I am showing them all. I want them to be able to edit and save on a table.